# What is the difference between a random variate and realization of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, terminology

According to Wikipedia, a [random variate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variate)  is a particular outcome of a random variable, whereas a [realization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(probability)) is the observed value of a random variable.

However, it's not clear to me what is the difference between the two. What is the difference and relation between a *random variate* and *realization* of a random variable?

Suppose we have a coin toss experiment with sample space $\Omega=\{\text{heads},\text{tails}\}$, with an associated random variable $X$ such that:

$X(\omega )={\begin{cases}1,&{\text{if}}\ \ \omega ={\text{heads}},\\0,&{\text{if}}\ \ \omega ={\text{tails}}.\end{cases}}
$

Can I say that the realizations of $X$ are either $1$ or $0$ (before the experiment), and that for an actual observation of the experiment where I tossed heads, $X$ resulted in the random variate $1$? Or, is it the other way around? Or, can I use them interchangeably?

Comment: "What is the difference and relation between a random variate and realization of a random variable?" None, as the page clearly indicates: "In probability theory, a random variable is a measurable function from a probability space to a measurable space of values that the variable can take on. In that context, those values are also known as random variates"...